# Initial value problem, not sure where to begin!

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

> Show that the function $y(t)=t^2$ satisfies the initial value problem 
>   $\frac{dy}{dt}=2\sqrt{y}, t\geq{0}; y(0)=0$
>
> Show that this initial value problem does not have a unique solution, by giving another
>   function which solves the same problem

I dont know if I am just over complicating things but i dont understand where to start with this, and if im missing something?

Is it as simple as to say:
$y(t)=t^2$ therefore $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2t$ now rearanging the first equation gives $\sqrt{y} = t$, subbing into the second equation gives $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2\sqrt{y}$

Comment: Try $y(t)=0$.  ${}{}{}$

Comment: Start by showing that the function $y(t)=t^2$ satisfies the given IVP. Is the derivative of $t^2$ equal to twice the square root of $t^2$? Is $t^2=0$ when $t=0$?

Comment: @Ian ive edited the equation with what I think is the answer, am i right with it?

Comment: @LaurenBathers Sure, that shows that $y(t)=t^2$ works. Now show that $y(t)=0$ also works.

Comment: @Ian how would i find another problem with the same solution?

Comment: @LaurenBathers Picard-Lindelof gives a hint: this can never happen if the right hand side is Lipschitz continuous with respect to $y$. This suggests that you might get the same situation with $y'=y^c$ for $0<c<1$; for instance you do with $c=2/3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this $$y(t)=\begin {cases} 0 \quad \qquad \;\;\,\text {if} \quad 0 \le t <1\\ \\ (t-1)^2 \quad \text {if} \quad t \ge 1 \end {cases}$$